# How to get a video thumbnail without any loss in quality on an embedded Vimeo video?

Tags: javascript, vimeo, video-thumbnails

I'm working on my company's website and we're embedding videos on some pages. We use Vimeo's custom thumbnail's feature but final rendition is ugly.

Does anyone know how to set a thumbnail on Vimeo vids without losing the original picture's quality ? I've heard of a javascript trick for example ?

Link on my website: http://radianceconseil.com/creation-sites-web-haute-savoie/

And here is the original picture : http://www.radianceconseil.com/images/sites-vitrine-accueil-Vimeo.jpghttp://www.radianceconseil.com/images/sites-vitrine-accueil-Vimeo.jpg

As you can see, there's a huge loss of quality!

Answer (score 1):

Well the thumbnail is beyond your control (Vimeo is generating the image and they have chosen a low quality (it looks like high level JPEG compression), Vimeo says that they will serve a higher resolution thumbnails [based on the embed size](http://vimeo.com/forums/feature_requests/topic:32794).  However you can replace it with a locally hosted image called a "[poster](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_video_poster.asp)" if you use the HTML5 video tag or you can add the image and use some JavaScript to replace it with the iframe on click.

Comment: Thank you very much Jason,

I think I'm using the HTML5 video tag on my site. Do you know how to use a poster picture ?

Comment: checkout the link on the word "poster".  You add the attribute poster="image.jpg" and the image will replace the video in it's initial state.